# Android Exception Caught While Determining Current Location

Tags: android, google-maps

When the MapFragment is opened, camera animates to the given position:
[image: Initial position].

When I click navigation button (top right), it animates to my current location:
[image]

The exception occurs when I click the navigation button while the first animation is being processed.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
```

According to code, the button must be disabled until GoogleApiClient is connected, however, it seems to be enabled anyways.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mMountainItems = MountainsUtils.get().getMountainItems();

    getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            updateUI();
        }
    });

    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    setCurrentLocation();
                    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                }
            })
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_allmountains, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_locate);
    searchItem.setEnabled(mClient.isConnected());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_locate:
            if(mClient.isConnected()){
                if (hasLocationPermission()) {
                    findCurrentLocation();
                }else {
                    requestPermissions(LOCATION_PERMISSIONS,
                            REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            }else{
                Snackbar.make(getView(), "Location is not identified yet", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void findCurrentLocation(){
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }

    LatLng myPoint = new LatLng(
            mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    boundsBuilder.include(myPoint);
    MarkerOptions myMarker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(myPoint);
    mMap.addMarker(myMarker);
    animateCamera(boundsBuilder);

}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void setCurrentLocation(){
    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setNumUpdates(1);
    request.setInterval(0);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(mClient, request, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    mCurrentLocation = location;
                    Log.d(TAG, mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + " : " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
                }
            });
}`enter code here`
```

fragment_allmountains.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_locate"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"
              android:title="@string/search"
              android:enabled="false"
              app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    </menu>
```

The whole fragment code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bekabot/548cf5c7bfc941329e23ac913d17f2bd)
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you declared the INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes, I did. As written above, the app is able to find my location, but after the first camera animation fully ends. It fails to find it when I try to do at the moment of the animation.

Comment: can you post `findCurrentLocation()` as well?

Comment: It's not necessary that if your google client is connected, the location will not be null. You are just checking for location permissions. You should also check whether gps is on.

Comment: @karandeepsingh posted :)

Comment: @karandeepsingh also added setCurrentLocation method

Comment: is the log giving you current values? probably `onLocationChanged` is not getting called. its a normal null pointer exception.

Comment: @karandeepsingh actually it gives slightly different values all the time, do you mean I should change the way I get my current location?

Comment: You should call your `setCurrentLocation()` inside `findCurrentLocation()` and call `LatLng myPoint = new LatLng(
            mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    boundsBuilder.include(myPoint);
    MarkerOptions myMarker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(myPoint);
    mMap.addMarker(myMarker);
    animateCamera(boundsBuilder);` inside `onLocationChanged`

Comment: @karandeepsingh it solves the issue! Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call your `setCurrentLocation()` inside `findCurrentLocation()` and call

```
LatLng myPoint = new LatLng( mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), 
 mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()); 
LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = 
 new LatLngBounds.Builder(); boundsBuilder.include(myPoint); 
 MarkerOptions myMarker = new MarkerOptions() .position(myPoint); 
 mMap.addMarker(myMarker); 
animateCamera(boundsBuilder);
```

inside 
     `onLocationChanged`